# I am have a problem with my carousel. My 'navigation-auto' buttons are not showing their background color to indicate which picture is shown

Tags: radio-button, tailwind-css, carousel

[image: HTML screenshot 1]
[image: HTML screenshot 2]
[image: HTML screenshot 3]
[image: CSS screenshot 1]
[image: CSS screenshot 2]
[image: JavaScript screenshot 1]

My project also uses Tailwindcss

I can't seem to get my automatic navigation background color to be visible when clicked on

I have tried a z-index, moving the automatic nav sections order, trying 'realitve' and a few other things.

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6089612)

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I configured my tailwind.config.js for the spacing.
so umder my comment AUTOMATIC NAVIGATION START -in this section-
I added a top-109 which is 109px. This is in the first div.

```html
<div class="navigation-auto h-250 w-550 grid grid-cols-1 grid-rows-5 place-items-start absolute mx-4 my-4 top-109">

                        <div class="auto-btn1 justify-self-start row-start-1 border-2 border-solid border-orange-500 p-1.5 rounded-lg duration-1000"></div>
                        <div class="auto-btn2 justify-self-start row-start-2 border-2 border-solid border-orange-500 p-1.5 rounded-lg duration-1000"></div>
                        <div class="auto-btn3 justify-self-start row-start-3 border-2 border-solid border-orange-500 p-1.5 rounded-lg duration-1000"></div>
                        <div class="auto-btn4 justify-self-start row-start-4 border-2 border-solid border-orange-500 p-1.5 rounded-lg duration-1000"></div>
                        <div class="auto-btn5 justify-self-start row-start-5 border-2 border-solid border-orange-500 p-1.5 rounded-lg duration-1000"></div>
                    </div>
```